# Command line to move the contents of an unnamed folder

Tags: command-line, batch-file, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I am trying to do a batch that fixes my flash drive from shortcut virus infection. I want to move the files from an unnamed folder (Alt+255) to the root directory of my flash drive, what is hard is that I can't do that with the short name of the folder because it is variable (one time it is 00A0~1 the other is 9DEC~1) so I am thinking of making a command that loops through the folders and prompts them to the user to decide if this is the unnammed folder or no like so (" " is that the folder? (Y/N)) similar to the output of this command:

```
for /d %d in (*) do rmdir /s "%d"
```

, but it moves all the contents of it to the root directory not delete it. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off using VBScript or PowerShell for this instead.

VBScript:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

source     = "K:\"
quarantine = "C:\quarantine"

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^[^a-z0-9_-]"
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each fldr In fso.GetFolder(source).SubFolders
  If re.Test(fldr.Name) Then
    answer = MsgBox("Move " & fldr.Path & "'?", vbYesNo, "Folder Check")
    If answer = vbYes Then fldr.Move quarantine & "\"
  End If
Next
```

PowerShell:

```
$source     = "K:\"
$quarantine = "C:\quarantine"

Get-ChildItem $source -Force | ? {
  $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match '^[^a-z0-9_-]'
} | % {
  $answer = Read-Host "Move $($_.FullName)? [Y/n]"
  if ( $answer.Length -eq 0 -or $answer[0] -eq "y" ) {
    $_.MoveTo((Join-Path $quarantine $_.Name))
  }
}
```

Both solutions check the source folder for folder names not starting with an alphanumeric character, underscore, or hyphen, prompt the user, and (on confirmation) move that folder to the quarantine folder.

If you want to use the PowerShell version on Windows XP, you have to install the [Windows Management Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595) first. PowerShell is included with that package.

Comment: The VBScript gives me the following error http://imagebin.org/263576. Does the PowerShell work on Windows XP?

Comment: Typo. The variable name was supposed to be `fldr`, not just `f`. The PowerShell version works on WinXP if you install the Windows Management Framework first. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
for /d %%i in (*) do echo %%~i |findstr "ECHO is" >nul&& move "%%~i" ELSEWHERE
```

This may move the folder   to `ELSEWHERE`.

---

```
for /d %%i in (*) do echo %%~i |findstr "ECHO is" >nul&& rd "%%~i"
```

This may remove the folder  .

Comment: It didn't show a y/n question to let the user decide if this is the folder he want to manipulate (move or delete). It also didn't moved any files. Here is the output http://imagebin.org/263569

Comment: It might depend on local settings. Please show the output of `echo`  at the command prompt.

Comment: Hopefully you don't have a folder `ECHO is`  :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
@echo off
set "var="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b') do (
echo "%%a"
set /p "var=Is that it? press enter for no and Y for yes: "
  if defined var (
   attrib -h -s -r -a "%%a" /d
   move "%%a\*.*" \
 )
set "var="
)
```

Comment: Sorry - it is air code (untested).  I corrected a mistake in it so try it again.